# I would like to be clarified about re-entry visa

Tags: visas

Can I get a re-entry student visa to Sweden after been convicted in Denmark? Detail: before I was convicted my resident permit expired and when I applied for a renewal in jail I was refused and told I have been banned for 2 years. After my sentence of 30 months, I was banned in Denmark for life. I was not given any paper about my EU ban and when I ask in Denmark and the police in Belgium they told I can travel back to any other EU country. Please I need clarification if it possible to come back to the EU after 4 years since my conviction.

Answer (score 5):

A complete answer to your question is difficult. When you ask "can I get" do you want to know if it is possible or do you want to know if it will probably happen? I will try to explain in simple words.

- Sweden **is not required** to give you a visa. They can make that decision.
- Sweden **is allowed** to let you enter. They can make that decision.
- I do not think that Sweden **will** give you a visa. We do not know all the details of your case, so we can not be sure what Sweden will do.

*(The EU/Schengen states retain the sovereign right to grant residency status, regardless of adverse information from other partner nations, or even in their own databases. That does not mean they will normally override the visa decisionmaking process that way.*

*A 30-month conviction in Denmark means a quite serious offense or many repeat offenses, they do not give multi-year prison sentences lightly. We do not know if there are reasons to make a visa more likely, family reunifications or the like.)*